# How to change default python from /usr/bin/python to /usr/local/bin/python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

Currently when I enter command `which python`, I get /usr/bin/python. But I also have python in /usr/local/bin and that's the one I like to use since my pip is located in /usr/local/bin as well. Both python are v2.7.16 and I'm using mac. What's the best way to switch default python from /usr/bin/python to /usr/local/bin/python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to override the system python. You merely want to rearrange your path to place /usr/local/bin ahead of /usr/bin. Honestly, you should be using /usr/bin/python3, as 2.7.16 has been EOL'd. That said, if your heart is set on using python2, [install pip](https://pip-installer.org) and then install [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/) before creating an environment with 2.7.16 for yourself using virtualenv and using that for all your python needs.

Comment: After I run pip install virtualenv, I run python -m virtualenv venv then I get "No module named virtualenv". Also when I run python -m pip then I get "No module named pip". My guess is because pip is located at /usr/local/bin but python is located at /usr/bin, I'm getting this error. Is there any other way to put /usr/local/bin/python ahead of /use/bin/python?

Comment: Run python with a full path, not just python. To find out which path, check the file yielded by `type pip`

Comment: When I run command "type pip", I get /usr/local/bin/pip. So u are saying I should try "/usr/local/bin/python -m virtualenv venv", correct?

Comment: That's spot on!

Comment: Thank you! It works now! It's quiet exhausting to type "/usr/local/bin/python" every time, but I'm happy with this for now.

Comment: That's why I instructed you to create a virtualenv for yourself and use that by `source $VENV_PATH/bin/activate`